# Safe way to connect with private git repository on a public computer

Tags: git, passwords, ssh-keys

I am working on a project partially on my laptop and partially on the PC in The University's Lab. On that PC I have only guest access and share profile with other students. I created a private repository on GitLab and now I would like to be able to connect to it from University's PC in such a way that others cannot clone my repo too. The public PC is running Windows 7. First solution that comes to my mind is to disable storage of passwords in Windows Credential Manager so it would ask for credentials every time I try to connect to my git repo, however I suppose I need an administrative rights to do that. Another option is to set an SSH authentication but as far as I know then my private key would have to be stored on a public PC what does not sound like safe.

Comment: In the university labs I've worked in a decade ago I had my own unique account tied to my university credentials. Your university does not offer this? Really, if there is any need to privacy, you should not be working on the U public account computers at all. Or if you are, you should VPN to a VM somewhere else.

Comment: There is no secure ways to do anything on a computer controlled by an untrusted party. If you trust university, use means to handle private data they provide. Usually your desktop and documents are considered private, but you want to confirm that with administration.

Comment: Windows password storage can be purged manually.

Answer (score 1):

- Install, configure and use [Plink with Git](http://www.mainelydesign.com/blog/view/git-plink-for-ssh-on-windows) for ssh:// repos
- For keys in Pageant you have only to have two files (public and private keys) and know password for private key (with really strong password your private key even can be stored in public place, public key isn't secure data in any case)

Comment: Can I use ssh-agent available in Git for Windows instead? Will the effect be the same as what you meant?

Comment: @BartholomeusR Yes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fully secure your information on a computer administered by someone else; they will always have ways to get access to any information that is stored on or even just goes through that computer if they have even a moderate amount of motivation to do so. That said, there are some steps you can take to limit the possible damage they can do.

You definitely want to use SSH, create a new SSH key only for use from that computer, and make sure that you have a strong passphrase on that key. You should also restrict, as much as possible, what can be accessed with that key. Rather than adding the key to your main GitLab account, I would create a second GitLab account with a fork of that private repo, give your main account full access to the fork, and run all commits sent to or from the lab machine through that second account.

You'll want to regularly use your laptop and main credentials to fetch any new changes from your master repo and push them over to the fork repo, and pull new commits from the fork repo (if you even do any from the lab machine) and, after carefully examining them to make sure they really are the commits you made, bring them back to the main repo.

You should certainly remove the lab machine's key from the second GitLab account when you're no longer need to use the lab machine, and you could even consider disabling that key on that second account when you're not using it (overnight, over weekends, whatever).